# Packing circles in d3 with variable padding/overlap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, padding, overlap, circle-pack

I'm trying to use the D3 circle pack layout that allows variable overlap/jamming in order to confine the circles to a set radii. The existing D3 circle pack layout will of course scale the outer circle to encompass the inner items but I need that outer circle to be a specific value.

In essence I need the inner circles to allow overlap, but only so much as to fit within the outer circle. I've tried negative padding values but it doesn't cover all cases especially well and results in more overlap than necessary.

Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you would need a different algorithm/implementation in your case. You should however be able to set the radius of the outer circle by setting the size of the layout.

Comment: Yes, I have been able to manipulate the zero-depth outer circle to be the correct size. The challenge is the inner circles do not correctly conform to it. By setting the padding to a negative value I can squish it in there, but it doesn't account for large variances in inner circle radii.

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to reposition all the circles (ie nodes) after the pack layout does its own positioning. It would take a bit of geometry calculations, but doesn't require a complex algorithm. You can get each cluster's actual radius, as yielded by the pack layout, and you know the radius you want it to have. So then you could loop over all the nodes and proportionally shift their center positions towards the center of their parent node.

Comment: That sounds about right. But how would you determine how much to move each circle?

Comment: All circles converge (i.e move) towards the center. Each circle moves proportionally to its distance from the center. A circle sitting on the edge of the cluster (such that its edge is tangent to the edge of the parent circle surrounding the cluster) would move the most. The amount it moves equals the difference between *actual* radius and *desired* radius of the cluster. A circle sitting in the exact center of the cluster would move zero. Anything between is a fraction.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  I have the same use case and am looking for some examples of solutions that address the need.